# Django rest frame work; Combining data from different models doesnot work

Tags: python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I tried combining data from two models. the serializers look like this.

```
class FindOwnerSaveSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):



    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'first_name', 'last_name','image')
        #fields = ('__all__')

class SaveSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    content = FindOwnerSaveSerializer(source='user',read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Save
        fields = ('project_id','content')
```

The save model looks like this

```
class Save(models.Model):
    project_id = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
```

and the view looks like this

```
class SaveView(UpdateAPIView):
    serializer_class = SaveSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def get_queryset(self):
        try:
            return Save.objects.filter(user_id=self.request.user)
        except Exception as e:
            logger.error(e)
            return Response(data='false')

    def get_object(self):
        try:
            if Project.objects.get(project_id=self.request.data['project_id']):
                return Response(data='true')
        except Exception as e:
            logger.error(e)
            return Response(data='false ')
```

the response keep looking like this. No user data is comming in.

```
[
    {
        "project_id": 78
    }
]
```

What could be the problem.Iam using django 2.2.7 and rest framwework 3.10.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your source referrence, it should be `source='user_id'` not `source='user'`

```
class SaveSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    content = FindOwnerSaveSerializer(source='user_id',read_only=True) # not `source='user'`

    class Meta:
        model = Save
        fields = ('project_id','content')
```